# useState what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm creating an app that reads the alarm state of several ELK alarm systems. I'm using useState to process the data that I am receiving via socket.io from my server. The data that the server is streaming is an array of arrays.

This is the code that I am using:

```
const [startData, updateData] = React.useState([]);

  const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

  socket.on('data', (dta) => {
    updateData(dta.data);
  });
```

If I console.log(startData) then it becomes evident that my code is causing an infinite loop. I read through examples of users in this forum with similar issues but I wasn't successful in tailoring their solutions to my problem. I was somewhat able to manage the amount of requests with setTimeout but after the app is running for about 2 hours, the page becomes unresponsive (memory leak????).

Do you people have any suggestion on how I could improve my code?

Comment: You should put socket.on in useEffect hook

Answer (score 3):

listening to a socket should only happen *once*, also this is a *side effect*, both are indicators that these should be inside a `useEffect` hook:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");

   socket.on('data', (dta) => {
     updateData(dta.data);
   });
 }, []);
```

Unlike the functions body, which will be run on every rerender, the effect hook will only run on specific state changes, or only once in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this solution which takes care of the infinite loop. But when I implement it then my alarm indicators don't re-render when the alarm state changes (when I arm/disarm the alarm system). I'm using bootstrap badges to show if the underlying alarm system is armed or disarmed. I have an event emitter on my express server that streams the alarm state changes to the client. How could I change the useEffect hook so that it registers any event changes that are being streamed?

Answer (score 0):

actually as Jonas said you should call socket once:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client"; 

const [startData, updateData] = React.useState([]);
  const endpoint= "http://localhost:5000";
  useEffect(() => {

       //Very simply connect to the socket
       const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);

       //Listen for data on the "outgoing data" 
       socket.on("outgoing data", (dta)=>updateData(dta.data));
       });
    }, []);
```

this is a good example : [express socket react](https://codeburst.io/isomorphic-web-app-react-js-express-socket-io-e2f03a469cd3)

Comment: Thank you for your response, like in the example above, when I implement this solution then my client is not listening for alarmstate changes from my server anymore. The client doesn't react anymore if I arm/disarm the alarm systems. If I use my solution with setTimeout then my client is displaying it correctly if I arm/disarm the system but the performance of the app is getting progressively worse - until it becomes unresponsive.

Comment: See this article https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34